# Windows 7 to Windows 7 Remote Desktop Not working, XP to 7 working fine

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I have a small home network and recently I tried to enable remote desktop for one of the PC's. I have a mix of Windows 7, Windows Vista and XP runing alongside Ubuntu, centos and others (some virtual, some real).
I have a few Windows 7 PC`s that can be connected to using remote desktop from inside and outside the network (port redirects on routers, etc, etc) and some XP ones.

The trouble is when I tried to do the same thing to a Windows 7 laptop I discovered I can't connect to it from another Windows 7 PC inside the home network. To sum it up

Working: XP --> Windows 7
not working: Windows 7 --> Windows 7

What I tried

- disable and enable remote desktop (my computer -> remote settings)
- removing and adding users to the remote settings window
- adding a new user to the machine, administrator or 'normal' user
- checking the firewall settings on the machine and set 'allow' to remote desktop for both 'home/work' and 'public' networks

Any tips on what should I do next? 
It displays ' .. secure connection' and after that the window with 'Your security credentials did not work' and it lets me try again with another user/password..

Answer (score 1):

It might be a firewall issue.

Check what you did against this article :
[Configure Remote Desktop Access on Windows 7 Systems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx).

Comment: thank you, i already did all that... if it would be a firewall issue i wouldn't be able to connect from some pc's

Comment: 1. So you are absolutely sure that Remote Desktop is allowed through Windows Firewall? 2. Do you connect using IP address or host name ? 3. Have you renamed any user account ? 4. Does the account have a password ? Also see [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-can-t-I-connect-using-Remote-Desktop-Connection).